# What is the effect of having open transaction in SQL Server for too long?

Tags: sql-server-2012, transactions

I'm just wondering what happens if you opened a transaction in SQL Server and forgot to commit or roll it back? Will the server be down? Let's say you left it for 3 days.

There are also users who are using it for too long assuming that the other users did not know that there is an unclosed transaction (let's just assume that the users are just inserting data on the database).

What are the consequences of this action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server such wont be down.

Here are few things that may happen

1.Table might be totally blocked
2.Since this transaction is not committed,log space reusing wont happen
3.Number of locks taken *96 bytes amount of memory will be blocked
4.memory reserved for this query execution might not be released

Comment: even for three days?

Comment: So it will not blow up ?

Comment: if you  are ok with whole table blocking and log space growing out(which are very big issues in themselves) ,then you can be fine

Comment: Then what if it is not?

Comment: @JanLeeYu can you please elaborate question ?

Comment: I already have an answer here


  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/142305/what-is-the-effect-of-having-an-opened-transaction-in-mssql-for-too-long  Thank you so much for spending a little time for this question.

Comment: @JanLeeYu:Great you found a solution